# Not taking reference from node_modules while creating angular 6 from VS-2017

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017, angular6, node-modules

I have created one angular 6 application using visual studio 2017. 
[image]

Here is the screenshot for my visual studio project (Angular).

[image]

As you can see I have added one new component and **service** named as **Todo**.
When I am adding todo.service.ts I need to add some references of angular modules so that I can avail HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams , catchError, tap, map features.

But here seems like **I am not able to refer the path to the angular module** package which we can easily refer while creating project using cli command because there we have **node_modules** folder where we have all packages and importing file using below command

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

but here in VS-2017 I am not able to refer the package. 
It give me an error like "can not find modules"

Here is the screen shot for the same.

[image]

Please suggest me what to do here how to refer to angular packages while creating angular project in VS-2017.

Note there is no error in referring to the package because the same code is **working while creating project using angular CLI command.**

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to directory where package.json file is placed

Run

```
npm install
```

If still the issue persists

Install required package using npm:

```
npm i <package-name> --save
```

Comment: OK.. I have tried this but it's not working even no changes I can see to this ClientApp folder...

Comment: Run in the directory where package.json file is available.

Comment: I have  deleted the existing node_module folder and then installed it again. but still no luck.

Comment: Close and reopen project

Comment: did but no luck :(

Comment: npm install --save rxjs@5.5.2

install latest version of rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Do this ,
Replace /common/http to common only

Same for operators

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..

1. You can rename or deleted the existing node_modules folder.
2. Then create new project using angular-cli command.
3. Then paste the copy the node_modules(step 2) to my .NET folder (step1).

Now, it start working.

Thanks for your all suggestion guys..